# Should I hand a component all @inputs() seperatly or just hand over an ID/ object?

Tags: angular, components

I am not sure what way is best (or just better) practice in writing Angular code. As I want to improve my code quality, could you give me some advice?

As an example, a custom list of custom elements:

```
<custom-list>
  <custom-item
    *ngFor="let obj of objects"
  ></custom-item>
</custom-list>
```

Should I either handle all the complexity inside `custom-item` like this

```
<custom-list>
  <custom-item
    *ngFor="let obj of objects"
    [obj]="obj"
  ></custom-item>
</custom-list>
```

where `custom-item` maps obj to a label, color, layout etc. **or** spread it out over many `@inputs()` like this?

```
<custom-list>
  <custom-item
    *ngFor="let obj of objects"
    [id]="obj.id"
    [label]="obj.label"
    [icon]="obj.icon"
    [color]="obj.color"
    [someProperty]="magicService.someProperty"
  ></custom-item>
</custom-list>
```

Edit: **Or** pass only an ID-property and get all relevant data inside each `custom-item` from a storage-service?

I'm not sure whether I should keep interfaces slim or my components simple and stupid. For any advice on best practice I would be truly grateful.

Also does it make a difference if some of the rendering-relevant properties are item-related or list-related (like borders in betweeen etc.)?

Comment: I think if your `obj` is a type of `custom-item` you should pass on only `obj`

Comment: Hello NechiK, thank you for your reply! :) In this case, would you pass the whole obj or just an id to get the obj inside custom-icon from a shared service?

Comment: I think you should just pass the whole obj, because you already received the list. In this case `custom-item` component is stupid component

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely pass the whole object to your component, because:

- One of general ideas behind component-driven programming is to make components reusable. Imagine if you're using that component on few places and you should add a new property. You have to walk through all places in your code and ensure that the new paramter will be provided as `Input` on all possible places.
- If "child" component is used only for displaying data and have some simple user actions (e.g. button clicked, etc) - try to keep it as "dumb" as possible. You'll add more complexity to your code by adding dependency service from where you can fetch the data for your item.

In addition, you can use more verbose names for your Inputs, e.g. `item` (or whatever you choose, related to the context of the component) is far better than simply `obj`.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have data in your parent component then you should pass the object to the child, no need to call the api again.